# Camel <packageScan> not working?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

Using Camel 2.15.2, Spring 4.1.7.RELEASE.

Project: [camel-example-cxf-tomcat](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-cxf-tomcat)

Route is created:

```
  <bean id="myRoutes" class="org.apache.camel.example.cxf.CamelRoute"/>

  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilder ref="myRoutes"/>
  </camelContext>
```

Route is not created:

```
  <bean id="myRoutes" class="org.apache.camel.example.cxf.CamelRoute"/>

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <packageScan>
            <package>org.apache.camel.example.cxf</package>
            <excludes>*Hide*</excludes>
        </packageScan>
    </camelContext>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue because, camel package scan will ignore already instantiated classes. So remove your below code and try.

`<bean id="myRoutes" class="org.apache.camel.example.cxf.CamelRoute"/>`

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Please share the error you are getting while creating routes.

The `<package> and <packageScan>` will skip any classes which has already been created by Spring etc. So if you define a route builder as a spring bean tag then that class will be skipped. You can include those beans using `<routeBuilder ref="theBeanId"/> or the <contextScan>` feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
<packageScan>
    <package>---specify package containing route here---
    </package>
</packageScan>
```